# ld: framework not found IDZSwiftCommonCrypto

Tags: ios, swift, commoncrypto

I have installed the `pod libcommoncrypto`, the path is 
`<project>/Pods/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto/*.swift` files

I fail to understand why `Xcode` is not able to find a framework installed by the `pod`.

**Edit** (Podfile)

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
project 'myproject.xcodeproj'
target 'myproject' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Toaster'
  pod 'libCommonCrypto'
end
```

[image: Library Project]

**Edit : CommonCrypto not found**
[image: CommonCrypto not found]

Comment: Can you provide a project exposing these problems?

Comment: Can you provide the podfile?I think we have insufficient info...

Comment: it should be part of Pods_SwiftCommons.framework in your main project. Pod subproject will download and have dependent frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently have `IDZCSwiftCommonCrypto` and `Toaster` as explicit entries in your "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", not as part of you cocoapods. Remove those two and try again, these should be added to your app only via `Pods_SwiftCommons.framework` that cocoapods creates for you.

Also: `pod 'libCommonCrypto'` does not create any files named `IDZSwiftCommonCrypto` at all, instead I find `Pods/libCommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.{h,swift}`, as I would expect. `IDZSwiftCommonCrypto` is another pod, unrelated to libCommonCrypto, if you still have those files I'd recommend cleaning your your Pods directory and running `pod update` again.

Comment: `Pods/libCommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.{h,swift}` is there. I removed the `IDZCSwiftCommonCrypto and Toaster`, still the same issue.

Comment: Weird. I would try this: `pod deintegrate`, `rm -rf Pods`, `pod update`. Make doubly sure that you don't have any explicit frameworks except `Pods_SwiftCommons.framework`, then show the full error context like in your original screenshot.

Comment: Now I get `CommonCrypto` module not found.

Comment: Works for me when I add the Pod to my project. Try cleaning your project (Cmd-Shift-K) and also clearing our the derived data (Cmd-Shift-Alt-K)

Comment: I'm out of ideas, tbh. Sorry. What I would do in your case is start from scratch: create a new empty project, add the Pods to it and make sure that works. If it does (and it should), add your existing files from the broken existing project to it.

Comment: This is what I did in the first place :). Crap, I'll try it again.

Comment: I tried again, created a new project it worked.. Thanks